# Regex select space between XML Tag

Tags: java, xml, regex

This is my String :

```
<AAA>aze rty ui</AAA>
```

I want to match my regex when there are spaces in my string.

I have tried that but it don't matches :

```
^(<AAA>)([\n\t ]+)(</AAA>)$
```

Comment: Why you need a regex? Use a parser.

Comment: Because i use an ETL and the XML Input is Reading like an Delimited file.( i can't change that.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to capture everything between the tags, try this instead

```
^<AAA>(.*?)</AAA>$
```

".*" matches anything and "?" forces reluctant matching (instead of greedy)

Comment: I just want to capture space char

Comment: You could use `^<AAA>(.*? .*?)</AAA>$` which will return the whole string but only if it has at least one space character.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to use `\s` to specify spaces, rather than a space.